# Reference Excel 2007 component in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I need some help on referencing an office component in C#3.5 win app .

How to add an Office2007/2010 Excel component in C#3.5 Windows Application toolbox and to use further as Drag and Drop.

using References unable to add the same (Excel2010/2007).

Please help in using the same.

Please note that I doesn't need 11.0 version spreadsheet as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Office PIA (primary interop assemblies) for referencing office application in your .NET app. Here is the re-distributable that you can use to get PIA for office 2007: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=59daebaa-bed4-4282-a28c-b864d8bfa513&displaylang=en

Comment: Doesn't get the solution relevant to my query. 
Please provide the solution or process of adding reference of Excel 14.0 or 12.0 2007/2010 component on C# Windows Application.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want - you have to add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll. This dll will be part of the package that I have mentioned. Please read this article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the component for IO, Use Excel Package plus.

That way you don't need Excel installed, and no com interoperability either.
http://epplus.codeplex.com/